# Concatenating multiple MySQL tables for search. Is this a good use of a MySQL View?

Tags: mysql, search, view

I'm trying to make it quick and easy to perform a keyword search on a set of MySQL tables which are linked to each other.

There's a table of items with a unique "itemID" and associated data is spread out amongst other tables, all linked to via the itemID.

I've created a view which concatenates much of this information into one usable form. This makes searching really easy, but hasn't helped with performance. It's my first use of a view, and perhaps wasn't the right use. If anyone could give me some pointers I'd be very grateful.

A simplified example is:

ITEMS TABLE:

```
itemID |  name 
------   -------
   1      "James"
   2      "Bob"
   3      "Mary"
```

KEYWORDS TABLE:

```
keywordID |  itemID |  keyword
------      -------   -------
   1           2        "rabbit"
   2           2        "dog"
   3           3        "chicken"
```

plus many more relations...

MY VIEW: (created using CONCAT_WS, GROUP_CONCAT and a fair few JOINs)

```
itemID |  important_search_terms 
------   -------
   1      "James ..."
   2      "Bob, rabbit, dog ..."
   3      "Mary, chicken ..."
```

I can then search the view for "mary" and "chicken" and easily find that itemID=3 matches. Brilliant!

The problem is, it seems to be doing all the work of the CONCATs and JOINs for each and every search which is not efficient. With my current test data searches are taking approx 2 seconds, which is not practical.

I was hoping that the view would be cached in some way, but perhaps I'm not using it in the right way.

I could have an actual table with this search info which I update periodically, but it doesn't seem as neat as I had hoped.

If anyone has any suggestions I'd be very grateful. Many Thanks

Comment: Based on he answers below it looks like what I really wanted was a "materialised view" which would take a snapshot of the data rather than performing the full query each time. MySQL doesn't seem to support this by default, but this link shows a possible way of implementing this : http://www.fromdual.com/mysql-materialized-views#implement

Comment: For simplicity, I plan to make an actual table with this cached data and update it periodically, but only if the data has been changed since the last update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, a view is nothing more than making it easier to read what you query for but underneath perform the SQL-Statement lying underneath everytime.

So no wonder it is as slow (even slower...) as when you run that statement itself.

Usually this is done by indexing jobs (running at nighttime, not annoying anyone), or indexed inserts (when new data is inserted, checks run if it is a good idea to insert them into the indexed interesting words).

Having that at runtime is really hard and require well designed database structures and most of the time potent hardware for the sql server (depending of data amount).

Comment: thanks I think I'll be implementing this periodically, hopefully I'll be able to create a version which is simplified enough to run once an hour. I'll possibly do a "full" indexing job every 24 hours too...

Answer (score 1):

A MySQL view is not the same as a materialized view in other SQL languages.  All it's really doing is caching the query itself, not the data needed for the query.

The primary use for a MySQL view is to eliminate repetitive queries that you have to write over and over again.

Comment: thanks for the "Materialized View" terminology - that's what I ideally wanted

Answer (score 1):

You've made it easy, but not made it quick.  I think if you look at the EXPLAIN for your query you are going to see that MySQL is materializing that view (writing out a copy of the result set from the view query as a "derived table") each time you run the query, and then running a query from that "derived table".

You would get better performance if you can have the "search" predicate run against each table separately, something like this:

```
SELECT 'items' AS source, itemID, name AS found_term 
  FROM items WHERE name LIKE 'foo'
 UNION ALL
SELECT 'keywords', itemID, keyword 
  FROM keywords WHERE keyword LIKE 'foo'
 UNION ALL
SELECT 'others', itemID 
  FROM others WHERE other LIKE 'foo'
```

-or-

if you don't care what the matched term is, or which table it was found in, and you just want to return a distinct list of itemID that were matched

```
SELECT itemID
  FROM items WHERE name LIKE 'foo'
 UNION
SELECT itemID
  FROM keywords WHERE keyword LIKE 'foo'
 UNION
SELECT itemID 
  FROM others WHERE other LIKE 'foo'
```

Comment: thanks, you're right, it will speed things up, but I'm hoping to use my materiaized data to do more complex searches in the long run and so this might become harder to manage. I'm planing to have a few columns of concatenated data, each with a weight, so for instance the first most important column might contain the title and the keywords, the second might contain the description etc. hopefully I'll then be able to search different types of data in one, consistent manner. That's the grand plan anyway... :)